# How To Add Validation in Textbox in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

What I need:

- When User Enter a mail address in text box then commas (,) should Seprate email address.

  i have used Example of jquery Autocomplete here is the url:http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple.
- i want that user enter multiple email address in textbox and (,) should seperate each email address.

  - here is the snapshot that i want :http://postimg.org/image/z7tv89bab/

    ```
     $(function() {
     var availableTags = [
     "af@gmail.com",
     "af1@gmail.com",
    "af2@gmail.com",
    "af3@gmail.com",

     ];
    function split( val ) {
     return val.split( /,\s*/ );
     }
    function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
     if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
     $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
     event.preventDefault();
    }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
       response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
      availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
      },
     focus: function() {
     // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
     var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
       terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
       return false;
      }
     });
    });
    ```

    Tag programming languages:

Comment: You told us what you want, now show us what you tried.

Comment: YES, we're not here to do all your job.

Comment: It's the user who enter the commas ? so what do you want to do ? after submitting the form, you want mails in an array that's it ? it yes you just have to $mails = explode(',',$_POST['mails_textarea']) ;

Comment: i want that like ex af@gmail.com(after domian name)(,) should seperate each domain name

Comment: yeah but you want it where ? After submitting (so in PHP) or Before / while editing the form (so in JS) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery validation plugin to validate  textbox.

// Code to accept multile mails

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("multiemail", function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var emails = value.split(','),
        valid = true;

    for (var i = 0, limit = emails.length; i < limit; i++) {
        value = emails[i];
        valid = valid && jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, value, element);
    }

    return valid;
}, "Invalid email format: please use a comma to separate multiple email addresses.");
```

The above function should be used in validation js

```
var validator = $("#frmlogin").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            multiemail: true
        }
    });
```